# How to get value from a statement only once in Python

Tags: python, function, class, pygame

I have a class and within it I have a method which has a loop in it. What I want to be able to do is run a statement `milliseconds = 0` only once at the top.

However, when I run the attached code, it keeps resetting to 0. Then what I want is so the milliseconds can increase at a rate of 200 each time if goes through. I have tried putting the `milliseconds = 0` under the class or outside the class and it doesn't work. What can I do?

EDIT: my new question, how can I make it so Python can count to 5000 milliseconds before progressing to the next piece of code.

```
class Flag():
    def Flagrun(self):
        flagactive = 'No'
        milliseconds = 0
        flaggen = str(randint(1,4))
        milliseconds += 200
        print(milliseconds)

    if milliseconds > 1000:
        if flaggen == '1':
            window.blit(flag, (58,89))
            collisiondet()
            flagactive = 'Yes'
            milliseconds = 0

        elif flaggen == '2':
            window.blit(flag, (464,82))
            collisiondet()
            flagactive = 'Yes'
            milliseconds = 0 

        elif flaggen == '3':
            window.blit(flag, (343,215))
            collisiondet()
            flagactive = 'Yes'
            milliseconds = 0 

        elif flaggen == '4':
            window.blit(flag, (66,535))
            collisiondet()
            flagactive = 'Yes'
            milliseconds = 0
```

Comment: Should your `if` statements be inside the function? Inside `flagrun`,  `milliseconds=0` creates a local variable.

Comment: What did you do to put it "under the class or outside the class" that didn't work?

Comment: Where is the loop? Seems the code is incomplete. And as @cdarke said, you put milliseconds in the function, so it is a local variable.

Comment: use `self.miliseconds` in all code and set `self.miliseconds = 0` in `__init__`

Comment: i tried self.milliseconds still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a shared variable for multiple class objects you want to create.

Note : I am not changing your code logic, i am just updating the code to re-utilize the variable milliseconds on every object of Flag class.

**Code:**

```
class Flag():

_shared_state = {}
milliseconds = 0

def __init__(self):
    self.__dict__ = self._shared_state


def Flagrun(self):
    flagactive = 'No'
    flaggen = str(randint(1,4))
    self.milliseconds += 200
    print(milliseconds)

    if milliseconds > 1000:
        if flaggen == '1':
            window.blit(flag, (58,89))
            collisiondet()
            flagactive = 'Yes'
            milliseconds = 0


        elif flaggen == '2':
            window.blit(flag, (464,82))
            collisiondet()
            flagactive = 'Yes'
            milliseconds = 0


        elif flaggen == '3':
            window.blit(flag, (343,215))
            collisiondet()
            flagactive = 'Yes'
            milliseconds = 0


        elif flaggen == '4':
            window.blit(flag, (66,535))
            collisiondet()
            flagactive = 'Yes'
            milliseconds = 0
```

Comment: one "typo" - you need `self.milliseconds` instead of `milliseconds` in all `Flagrun`

Comment: class Flag():

    _shared_state = {}
    milliseconds = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self._shared_state

    def Flagrun(self):
        flagactive = 'No'
        milliseconds = 0
        flaggen = str(randint(1,4))
        milliseconds += 200
        print(milliseconds)
        
        if milliseconds > 1000:
            if flaggen == '1':
                window.blit(flag, (58,89))
                collisiondet()
                flagactive = 'Yes'
                milliseconds = 0

Comment: that was a mistake. whoops. ill post in the normal answering thing.

Comment: how can i delete comments

Comment: EDIT: my new question, how can i make it so python can count to 5000milliseconds before progressing to the next piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

(You really should ask a new question on a new post)

If you don't care about what the program does, and you just want it to wait 5 seconds then you can `import time` and then use `time.sleep(5)`. This will deactivate the program for five seconds, which is probably not what you want.

If you just want to make a little counter that continues the program after it hits 5000, you have two options:

```
while milliseconds < 5000:
    milliseconds += 1
```

After milliseconds hits 5000 or more, it will just exit the loop and continue on.

If you want to have something else increase the milliseconds variable, then just have any loop that contains whatever increases milliseconds, and do this:

```
while stuff_happens:
    # somehow increase milliseconds

    if milliseconds >= 5000:
        break


# then more code can run
```

Comment: That while-statement won't wait for 5000 milliseconds though. The while loop is executed at different speeds depending on the computer. My computer completed the code in less than 1 millisecond. What your looking for is something like `last = time.time(); while time.time() - last < 5; continue`. Although, this is problaby not the best why since it will eat much processor power during the while-loop. You probably should put in a `time.sleep(x)` in it but that would reduce its accuracy.

Comment: I already tried time.sleep but it stops the entire code which is not what I want. I'll try that while loop thing when I get a chance but like nort said it'll just finish in less then a millisecond. I need an actual millisecond timer.

Comment: ok so i tried the while miliseconds is less than 5000, increase it by 1. so it technically works and it does take a fair amount of time for it to get to 5000, but it is freezeing the entire game for some reason. when i launch the game it is waiting for it to reach 5000 before progressing to the next piece of code where it waits again. is there a way to fix this so only that block of code is waiting to progress. thanks again.

Comment: Could you show the code that seems to not be working? Also, unfortunately python will only run one block of code at a time. There are ways to work around it, but it's important to know. If one piece is processing slow, other pieces will also go slow if they're running in the same loop.

Comment: what would you like to me do? the post is in the question but im still stuck int he same place. thanks

Comment: Oh I know what's wrong. When you use a while inside a function (that's inside a loop) it will slow down the whole outer loop to finish that. Change the loop with milliseconds to "if", and see if that fixes it.